# How to properly create an audio file in Xcode that can be heard in iOS mail

Tags: xcode, ios5, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I have an app that has record and playback capabilities. These work fine. I can also email the audio file.

If I read the email on a computer, I can play the audio file.

I can read the email on an iDevice, but if I try to play the audio file,  I see something like QT pop up for a moment, but then, the message returns to the screen.

If I hold down the audiofile icon, I get a list of apps that can be used - but they are all document apps, not audio apps.

The soundfile has a .caf suffix (Core Audio Format).

My audio file is created like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary* recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[recordSettings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4]     forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSettings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:16]                           forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
[recordSettings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0]                    forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
[recordSettings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2]                              forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

NSError *error = nil;
audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]

initWithURL:soundFileURL settings:recordSettings error:&error];

if (error)
{
NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
// ALL IS OK, START RECORDING
//NSLog(@"DetailVC - recordAudio -  soundFilePath is %@", soundFile);
[audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
recordToggle = 1;

[autoCog startAnimating];
[audioRecorder record];     

recordingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                         target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(recordingOn)
                                                       userInfo:nil
                                                        repeats:YES];

}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might not be in the audio creation, but how you attach it to the email. Are you setting the MIME type correctly so the mail client knows how to read the data? For `.caf`, you should use the `audio/x-caf` MIME type.

Comment: I may have responded too quickly. Now I'm finding that the email attachment looks like a document :(

Comment: That sounds like the device doesn't have any apps that know how to play a .caf file (Yeah, I know that sounds counter-intuitive, since you are using a device to record this thing but that is the difference between having a framework/library in the OS that can do it and an app that does it). Either try downloading an app specifically for playing .caf, or try encoding it as an MP3 (or something more universal).

Sorry I can't be of more help, I don't have that much audio experience, so I'm coming at this from a generic 'data encoding' viewpoint.

Answer (score 1):

The code to solve the problem was:

```
NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:soundFile];
[mailer addAttachmentData:soundData mimeType:@"audio/mpeg" fileName:@"YourFile.mp3"];
```